# location.hash gets updated with value of a link's new hash that is replaced *after* a click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There is weird JavaScript-"HTML anchor hash"-"location hash" interplay happening that I can't understand. Here goes

```html
<div id="link"><a href="#foo">switch to foo</a></div>
```

```js
<script>
    const link = document.querySelector('#link > a');

    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        toggleFooBar(this.hash.substr(1));
    });

    toggleFooBar = function(type) {

        if (type === 'foo') {
            link.hash = '#bar';
            link.innerHTML = 'switch to bar';
        }
        else if (type === 'bar') {
            link.hash = '#foo';
            link.innerHTML = 'switch to foo';
        }

    };
</script>
```

On page load, the link displays **switch to foo** as expected. When I click on the link, the text changes to **switch to bar** *but* the `location.hash` changes to `#bar`. I was expecting that only the `link.hash` in the HTML would change to `#bar` while the `location.hash` would display `#foo` because that is what I clicked on in the first place. Seems like the `link.hash` and the `location.hash` are linked so that changing the `link.hash` even *after* the click has happened updates the `location.hash`. Obviously, this is not what I want. I want the `location.hash` to display the `link.hash` value that existed at the time of the `click`. And then, I want the `link.hash` to change to the new value so if clicked again, it can toggle back correctly.

What is the source of my error and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the source of my error and how do I correct it?

I believe the click event handler is executed **before** the default action (*) for the event happens. That means you are actually updating the hash abefore the URL is updated.

Demo of issue:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('#link > a');

link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  toggleFooBar(this.hash.substr(1));
});

toggleFooBar = function(type) {

  if (type === 'foo') {
    link.hash = '#bar';
    link.innerHTML = 'switch to bar';
  } else if (type === 'bar') {
    link.hash = '#foo';
    link.innerHTML = 'switch to foo';
  }

  // Only used to show current hash since code is run in an iframe
  setTimeout(() => console.log(window.location.hash), 100);
};
```

```html
<div id="link"><a href="#foo">switch to foo</a></div>
```

A simple solution would be to delay the modification of the element by using `setTimeout`:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('#link > a');

link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  toggleFooBar(this.hash.substr(1));
});

toggleFooBar = function(type) {

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (type === 'foo') {
      link.hash = '#bar';
      link.innerHTML = 'switch to bar';
    } else if (type === 'bar') {
      link.hash = '#foo';
      link.innerHTML = 'switch to foo';
    }
  }, 0);

  // Only used to show current hash since code is run in an iframe
  setTimeout(() => console.log(window.location.hash), 100);
};
```

```html
<div id="link"><a href="#foo">switch to foo</a></div>
```

---

*: Apparently "default action" is a legacy term. The latest spec uses the term "activation behavior". More information can be found on https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events

Comment: damn man, how on earth would I have figured this out without your help? So many thanks. Yes, a short delay makes it work like a charm.